# Discord TokenInvalid Error With .env file

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Here if I am passing the Discord Bot token like this

```
client.login(`MTEwOTgwNDk1NjYzMTk3ODAxNQ.GeNpaX.rl8qpXd7MDhq9AcC1pzHAwer7C2OVrvcAyPx4I`);
```

This is not giving any error, but if if I am passing it from the `.env` file this throws a TokenInvalid Error

```
client.login(process.env.TOKEN_KEY);
```

What can be the best solution for this error ?

Comment: What is the output of  `console.log(process.env.TOKEN_KEY)` ?

Comment: its showing a error of INVALID TOKEN

Comment: How can console.log() show that? Please insert the line I suggest somewhere before `client.login` and say us what's the response

Answer (score 0):

Double check if your `TOKEN_KEY` in your `.env` is exactly that token value. Also, you should not be sharing your token in public at all.

Alternatively, try `process.env["TOKEN_KEY"]` instead. Also try setting your environment variables in your OS instead of in `.env` file.

Comment: I have changed the token so no problem not for that i guess
and this answer dose not work. is there any other solution, I don't know how to setup environment variables in OS. can you explain

Comment: @AnimeshGupta try to check if you've entered the token with spaces. But as what @pierpy said, try run `console.log(process.env.TOKEN_KEY)` just to see if the token is displayed in the console.